# How can I set a path to load data from CSV file into PostgreSQL database in Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, csv

I need help, Docker does not initialize .sql file from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: someUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somePassword
      POSTGRES_DB: someDB
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "someUser" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

My docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ directory was set up manually, I copied my *.sql file into it, hoping it would be executing and populate my postgres database. It looks like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA retail;
CREATE TABLE retail.user_purchase (
    invoice_number varchar(10),
    stock_code varchar(20),
    detail varchar(1000),
    quantity int,
    invoice_date timestamp,
    unit_price Numeric(8,3),
    customer_id int,
    country varchar(20)
);


COPY retail.user_purchase(invoice_number,stock_code,detail,quantity,invoice_date,unit_price,customer_id,country)
FROM '/db_data/retail.csv' DELIMITER ','  CSV HEADER;
```

Any help is much welcome, struggling here

Comment: It doesn't look like you're providing anything to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory in the container at all.  When you say that directory was "set up manually", what have you actually done?

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the local file into the container using the volume.

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: someUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somePassword
      POSTGRES_DB: someDB
    volumes:
      - db_data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "someUser" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it partly helped. The COPY/FROM statement has not been executed, the table is there, but the CSV data has not been copied over.

Comment: Polite nudge for anyone that can help me please